# Periodic repaint of scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication

Tags: scala, scala-swing

If I run this example code

```
class ExampleGUIElement extends Panel
{
  preferredSize = new Dimension(100, 100)
  val rand : Random = Random
  override def paintComponent(g: Graphics2D) = g.drawLine(rand.nextInt(10),rand.nextInt(10),rand.nextInt(90) + 10 ,rand.nextInt(90) + 10)
}

object GUITest extends SimpleSwingApplication  
{
  def top = new MainFrame
  {
    contents = new ExampleGUIElement
  }
}
```

It obviously only shows the one line that has been draw initially. If I want a periodic repaint I normally would just make a Timer that calls repaint on the most outer JFrame.
But SimpleSwingApplication does not have this method, at least I can not find it, and calling top.repaint instead just does nothing. So how do you periodically repaint the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling `peer` on the `top` (see [`MainFrame`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.swing.MainFrame)), and then calling `repaint` on that:

```
top.peer.repaint()
```

Also, don't forget to call `top.pack()`.

Comment: This does not work for me either. I've made a timer with override def run = GUITest.top.peer.repaint() and it still does not update.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is dated, but I extracted your Panel into a val and added a timer to repaint it:

```
def top = new MainFrame
{
    val example = new ExampleGUIElement 
    contents = example
    val timer=new javax.swing.Timer(250, Swing.ActionListener(e =>
    { 
        example.repaint()
    }))
    timer.start()
}
```